# cant apply stylesheet to "input-validation-error " class

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add some style to the input-validation-error class which shows the ErrorMessage texts when validation fails but **nothing happens**, no style is applied

this is my stylesheet at wwwroot/css/style

```
.field-validation-error {
 color: #ff00;
}
.field-validation-error {
display: none
}
.input-validation-error {
 border: 1px solid #f00;background-color: #fee;
}
.validation-summary-errors {
 font-weight: bold;color: #f00;
}
.validation-summary-valid {
 display: none
 }
```

I have added a link element to the head section of my form page:

```
@model GuestResponse

@{ Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewpot" content="width=device-width"/>
<title>RsvpForm</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

<p>
    <label asp-for="Name"> Your Name: </label>
    <input asp-for="Name"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label asp-for="Email"> Your Email:</label>
    <input asp-for="Email"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label asp-for="Phone"> Your Phone:</label>
    <input asp-for="Phone"/>
</p>
<p>
    <label> Will You Attend?</label>
    <select asp-for="WillAttend">
        <option value=""> Choose an option </option>
        <option value="true"> Yes, I'll be There. </option>
        <option value="false"> No, i can't come. </option>
    </select>
</p>
<button type="submit"> Submit Rsvp</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Whats the problem here?

I found what the problem was, using Intellesense, it didn't insert "/" before CSS in href
href="css/styles.css"/>
it should be:
href="/css/styles.css"/>

Comment: You need to specify the correct path to your CSS. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641972/add-css-js-or-other-content-to-a-views-head-from-partial-views) or in the asp.net [forum](https://forums.asp.net/post/5878988.aspx)

Comment: I've copied codes from the book exactly as they were, and regarding specifying the correct path that's what said in the book:    " The link element uses the href attribute to specify the location of the stylesheet. Notice that the wwwroot folder is omitted from the URL. The default configuration for ASP.NET includes support for serving static content, such as images, CSS stylesheets, and JavaScript files, and it maps requests to the wwwroot folder automatically."